# In well designed code should you expect locking of weak_ptr to always succeed?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

When you wish to make an access using a weak pointer, you are first advised to get a strong pointer to the pointed object by locking.  Locking may not succeed in case the pointed object was deleted earlier.

It seems to me that unless you did something wrong in breaking the cycles to decide what is a weak pointer, locking will succeed.  So you are locking just to cross-check your design.

Is this correct?

I have seen some remarks about caching, but they seem like an abuse of weak_ptrs.  But of course one man's abuse is another man's innovation.  I would like to hear opinions.

Comment: Its a good question, unfortunately stack overflow isnt geared towards questions that solicit a suevey of opinion.  Its off topic here.

Comment: Note that if you think promoting the weak_ptr to shared_ptr will always succeed, and if you also think that the so-promoted weak_ptr will never be the last reference (that is to say, whatever strong reference you designed in, you designed to last as long as you hold your lock), then you could just as well have used a raw pointer instead of a weak_ptr. Error-detection in code that *could* have used raw pointers is *one* motivation for using weak pointers, but I don't believe that it is the motivation for their invention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `weak_ptr` only to break cycles, then yes, getting a `shared_ptr` from it should always succeed.

But that's not the only use.  Matthieu M. gives one example of using them.

You mention caching and that's a good use case for `weak_ptr` where there are no cycles, and I don't consider it an abuse at all.  If you have an object that some other part of the system (another thread, or a cache) owns and you want to store a reference to that object for possible later use, if you use a `shared_ptr` to refer to the object then you share ownership of it and will prolong its lifetime. If you are not sure you'll need the object later so don't want to prolong its lifetime you could use a `weak_ptr` and check if it still exists when you need it. If it doesn't exist you find a different object or create it again (which might be slow e.g. require a database query, which is why you wanted to reuse an existing object if possible.)

Comment: Heh, I was writing an answer very similar to this. I went on to say that usually, you'd prefer a soft reference rather than a weak reference for a cache. But sometimes you can afford to be pro-active about throwing things away, sometimes you actively want to drop the cache ASAP, and anyway C++ doesn't offer a soft reference, so you need to mess with new handlers.

Comment: I wasn't very happy with my description so feel free to make any edits to improve the answer or make the example less abstract.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the examples given by Kerrek SB and Matthieu M are similar to caching, but I agree there is no need to think of them as abuse.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than thinking of it as "locking", bear in mind that all you do is obtain another share in the ownership. The weak pointer itself doesn't own anything, so it can't be used directly.

The typical use for weak pointers probably lies in concurrent code. Suppose you have a collection of objects owned by shared pointers somewhere. You can then have another collection of weak pointers referring to those same objects (e.g. a collection of timers). A second thread may pick up the weak pointer, attempt to create a shared pointer from it, and upon success call, say, a timer routine on the object. If the task has already died at the time, then the shared pointer will be null and the second thread skips the task.

The crucial fact about `std::shared_ptr` is that its internal reference count is updated atomically, and so you *can* write code in the way I described and it will be race-free.

```
Thread 1                          Thread 2
--------                          --------
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Task>>   std::list<std::weak_ptr<Task>> todo;
add
remove                            for (auto wp : todo)
                                      if (auto p = wp.lock())
                                          p->do_work();
```

Comment: "First off, you're not "locking" anything" -- the member function is called `lock()`, so you'll need to take that up with the committee :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Why would you do that if you can write `if (std::shared_ptr<Foo> p(my_weak_ptr)) { p->use(); }`?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Hmm, maybe it's even better to write `if (auto p = my_weak_ptr.lock())`. Fair enough.

Comment: You'll have to take that up with the committee too ;-p Seriously, I think the notion of "locking" a weak pointer is a useful metaphor, but also I think I agree with you, the `weak_ptr` constructor of `shared_ptr` makes the `lock()` function not strictly necessary. I suppose some people prefer named conversion functions over one-arg constructors? And your `auto` example is certainly a nice way to write it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The `auto` style means you don't have to know the type, which is possibly an important advantage.

Comment: @KerrekSB, if you don't call lock and construct a shared_ptr directly it will throw instead of constructing an empty shared_ptr, lock() is useful for when you don't want to handle an exception.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ooh, I didn't realize that -- I thought it would construct a null pointer. Let me fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you should not.

Suppose you maintain a list of observers, upon destruction you would need to unsubscribe the observer from the object(s) it was observing, however that requires that the observer maintains a list of the entities it observes, leading to a cycle.

To simplify the design, it is simpler to introduce a level of indirection. A broker between the observer and the entity will allow the observer to be destroyed and the entity querying for its liveness.

How to ? Simply you can allocate a `std::shared_ptr<Observer>` and have an entity only retain a `std::weak_ptr<Observer>`, then when an entity iterate over its list of observers, it can cull the references to those who died since the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The use case where you have a `weak_ptr` which is invalid seems like a race condition/bad design.

`weak_ptr` should be used for accessing objects with strict life time, which the accessing object doesn't hold ownership

If you have an object with non-strict life time, you should use `shared_ptr`.